# How is the best way to merge array of hashes based on same value of some key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have some array of hashes with same keys. Like this below:

```
entities = [
  {type: :user, name: 'Tester', phone: '0000-0000'},
  {type: :user, name: 'Another User', phone: '0000-0000'},
  {type: :company, name: 'A.C.M.E.', phone: '0000-0000'},
  {type: :user, name: 'John Appleseed', phone: '0000-0000'},
  {type: :company, name: 'Aperture Industries', phone: '0000-0000'}
]
```

I need to organize them based on value of some key, generating a new hash with keys based on values of some key of original hash, like `type`.

I do this for organize:

```
by_type = {}
entities.each do |entity|
  by_type[entity[:type]] ||= []
  by_type[entity[:type]] << entity
end
```

Resulting on what I need:

```
by_type = {
  user: [
    {type: :user, name: 'Tester', phone: '0000-0000'},
    {type: :user, name: 'Another User', phone: '0000-0000'},
    {type: :user, name: 'John Appleseed', phone: '0000-0000'}
  ],
  company: [
    {type: :company, name: 'A.C.M.E.', phone: '0000-0000'},
    {type: :company, name: 'Aperture Industries', phone: '0000-0000'}
  ]
}
```

There is another way or an elegant method to organize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_by`:

```
entities.group_by { |entity| entity[:type] }
```